# How to convert a negative integer into two's complement binary form? (Java)

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

I need to convert numbers, positive and negative, into binary format - so, 2 into "00000010", and -2 into "11111110", for example. I don't need more than 12 bits or so, so if the string is longer than that I can just trim off the leading sign bits. It seems like `Integer.toBinaryString()` will do positive numbers, but is there one that can do negatives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Integer.toBinaryString` works for negatives too. :-) For example, `Integer.toBinaryString(-2)` returns 11111111111111111111111111111110.

If you take the rightmost 12 characters, you have the bottom 12 bits, as required.